# Android SQLiteOpenHelper.onUpgrade how handle database schema upgrade

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I have an app in Google Play store and I'm working on new version of it. There will be change in SQLite database scheme (new tables) + new ContentProviders.

I consider how to properly solve upgrade of database structure so that users when upgrading my app doesn't lose their current content and also will have created new tables.

Should I change: 
*** private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;** 
to:
 **private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2; ***

and somehow in onUpgrade() method place code that if detect that oldVersion was 1 and newVersion is 2. Will create new tables.

Now I have some dumb code there where if onUpgrade has been called the database has been destroyed and recreated... but I think that this method has never been called cause DATABASE_VERSION hasn't been changed. And I just uninstall and reinstall app while testing.

What is the best practice?

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Currently I use the following:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if(oldVersion < 2)
         //changes added in DBv2
    } 
    if(oldVersion < 3)
         //changes added in DBv3
    } 
   //so on...
}
```

This way ensures that changes are made to the database one after another in the correct order

Comment: I have in onUpgrade() calling of SomeProvider.SomeTable.onUpgrade() and I consider whether better to add this checks in each SomeTable.onUpgrade() or directly in SQLiteOpenHelper. onUpgrade()